# Combining two hypothesis tests

Tags: hypothesis-testing, p-value, multiple-comparisons, false-discovery-rate, familywise-error

I have data with $N$ genes, each having some $m$ observations. I am testing two hypothesis for each gene. These hypotheses are distinct (they test different parameters), but are assumed to be correlated due to the underlying science. They are distinct in the sense that they are measuring different parameter $\theta_1$ and $\theta_2$, and their summary statistics are different.

So for hypothesis $H_1$, I get a pvalue for each gene $p_{i,1} \forall i \in \{1...N\}$, and
for hypothesis $H_2$, I get pvalues $p_{i,2} \forall i \in \{1...N\}$. Now since I am conducting $N$ tests for each hypotheses, I apply BH multiple testing correction to the pvalues to get the equivalent FDR values. Call them $f_{i,1}$ and $f_{i,2}$ for all $i$.

Now, I am interested in genes that are significant in $H_1$ but null in $H_2$. So, I select those genes with $f_{i,1}<0.05$ and $f_{i,2}>.05$. Are these really different, or will these show up randomly because I am testing many genes? I argue that I've already taken care of the multiple testing problem by the FDR. For any gene, the probability of its false discovery in $H_1$ discovery after testing all $N$ genes is still just $f_{i,1}$. I don't think I can calculate the probability of a false negative in $H_2$. If use this criterion, what is my level of significance (i.e., the false discovery rate for selecting alternative $H_1$ and null $H_2$)? Does it depend on how many genes were significant for the alternative in $H_1$ and $H_2$ for FDR of 0.05?

Comment: Imagine there are true effects in H1 and H2, and your statistical procedure successfully detects the H1 effect but fails to detect the H2 effect.  Therefore, you include this gene in your list of genes significant in H1 but null in H2.  Does this constitute a false discovery?

Comment: @user43849 Yes, that would constitute a false discovery.

Comment: In that case, the answer depends on the distribution of true effect sizes in H2 and on the power of your tests to detect those effects.
Even if you can solve that problem, the non-independence of H1 and H2 is going to cause you a massive headache unless the correlation between them has some simple, known form.